# What is the REGEX for any number with a string(letters and punctuations)?

Tags: python, regex

I  have the following text:

INPUT:

```
mandatory NORMAL
P1000 NONE
of NONE
coastal NONE
35 NONE 
was NONE
ordered 
. NONE
With NORMAL
the NONE
typhoon 
out NONE
of NONE
the NONE
country NORMAL
local NORMAL
governments 
1000,000 NORMAL
```

I am using the following code to extract words that contain digits (e.g. `$100`, `1000.00`, `41AV90`, `9()-O87`, etc.) **and** replacing any word that comes after the words containing numbers with a `NUMBER` keyword:

```py
def tag_words(input):
    numbers = re.findall(r"\d+", input)
    tagged_text = st.tag(per_word(input))
    string_type = '\n'.join(' '.join(line) for line in tagged_text)
    filtered_text = re.sub(r"\bNONE(?=\n|$)", "NONE", string_type)
    return filtered_text
```

I've already tried different patterns but none return the expected output:

OUTPUT:

```
mandatory NORMAL
P1000 NUMBER
of NONE
coastal NONE
35 NUMBER 
was NONE
ordered 
. NONE
With NORMAL
the NONE
typhoon 
out NONE
of NONE
the NONE
country NORMAL
local NORMAL
governments 
1000,000 NUMBER
```

Comment: If there is even a single numeral character in the input, would you consider it as valid catch ?

Comment: @ZdaR Yes sir.  example: 4, 1233AAA, +4000-01

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a suggested solution that will do two things at once: 1) collect (extract) all the words that consist of digits and/or letters with at least 1 digit and 2) replace the following word with `NUMBER` in case there is a match.

Here is the regex I suggest:

```
([^\s0-9]*[0-9]\S*)\s+\w+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GHGX5x/1). Pattern details:

- `([^\s0-9]*[0-9]\S*)` - Group 1:

  - `[^\s0-9]*` - any 0+ chars other than whitespace and digits
  - `[0-9]` - a digit
  - `\S*` - any 0+ chars other than whitespace
- `(\s+\w+)?` - an optional Group 2:

  - `\s+` - 1 or more whitespaces
  - `\w+` - 1 or more word chars

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/tEwXZg):

```
import re
s = "mandatory NORMAL\r\nP1000 NONE\r\nof NONE\r\ncoastal NONE\r\n35 NONE \r\nwas NONE\r\nordered \r\n. NONE\r\nWith NORMAL\r\nthe NONE\r\ntyphoon \r\nout NONE\r\nof NONE\r\nthe NONE\r\ncountry NORMAL\r\nlocal NORMAL\r\ngovernments \r\n1000,000 NORMAL"
words = []
def repl(m):
    words.append(m.group(1))
    if m.group(2):
        return "{} NUMBER".format(m.group(1))
    return m.group(1)

res = re.sub(r"([^\s0-9]*[0-9]\S*)(\s+\w+)?", repl, s)
print("Result: {}".format(res))
print("Words: {}".format(", ".join(words)))
```

Full output:

```
Result: mandatory NORMAL
P1000 NUMBER
of NONE
coastal NONE
35 NUMBER 
was NONE
ordered 
. NONE
With NORMAL
the NONE
typhoon 
out NONE
of NONE
the NONE
country NORMAL
local NORMAL
governments 
1000,000 NUMBER
Words: P1000, 35, 1000,000
```

Comment: @Jack-Jack You are welcome. Please see my final edit. I finished re-formatting my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The change will be done at this line (I've already change it):

```
filtered_text = re.findall(r"^[\w()-.$]*$", result)
```

Note: I removed `\d` because `\w` represents all alphanumeric characters (letters and numbers). As you want to include some special characters, reason why I put it `()-.$` there.

Comment: sir what is the regex for any word after "^[\w()-.$]*$"?

Comment: Could you please clarify your question?

Comment: @Sege [Your regex](https://regex101.com/r/Q25wHA/1) is a bit misleading: `)-.` creates a range and actually matches `)`, `*`, `+`, `,`, `-` and `.`. Is that intended? Also, `re.findall` and a regex with anchors makes little sense (there will always be one single match).

Comment: 1000 NUMBER.  What is the regex for the word after the 1000? In this example it is the word NUMBER. I'm want to find all the word that comes after the ^[\w()-.$]*$.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, what is the right way to do it simple?

Comment: OP posted some update. See OP.

Comment: Thank you @WiktorStribiżew and for your link [Regex101](https://regex101.com)